# Extract maximum list based on a common element in lists in a list

Tags: python, list

I am wondering if it is possible to extract maximum list based on a common element in lists in a list. 
What I mean is that suppose we have the following list of lists:

```
list = [['p_1', [3, 4, 5, 6], 6.2],
        ['p_2', [3, 4, 5, 6], 8.4],
        ['p_3', [3, 7, 8, 9],9.1],
        ['p_4', [3, 4, 5, 6],8.2]]
```

My plan is to compare second element in each list with second element in other list and then if the second element is the same, choose the list with the highest third element. For example, the second elements of the first, second and forth lists are the same (i.e `[3,4,5,6]`). Now since `6.2 < 8.2 < 8.4` the second list will be chosen. In addition, since the second element of the third list is unique this list should also be chosen. In fact, the final list should look like the following list:

```
max_list = [['p_2', [3, 4, 5, 6], 8.4], ['p_3', [3, 7, 8, 9],9.1]]
```

I used the following code to modify the current list, but it does not work.

```
import itertools 
for i, k in itertools.combinations(list, 2):
    if i[1]==k[1]:
        if i[3]>= k[3]:
            list.remove(k)
        else:
            list.remove(i)
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic is right and you have almost found the solution. Here are your mistakes:

1. The inner list (e.g. `['p_1', [3, 4, 5, 6], 6.2]`) contains three items. So, the index of the last item is `2` and not `3` as you have written in your code. You should write `if i[2] >= k[2]:` instead of `if i[3] >= k[3]:`.
2. You have to check that an element is in the list `list` before to remove it. if not, you will get the exception `ValueError`.

Based on your logic, here is the working code:

```
import itertools

list = [['p_1', [3, 4, 5, 6], 6.2],
        ['p_2', [3, 4, 5, 6], 8.4],
        ['p_3', [3, 7, 8, 9],9.1],
        ['p_4', [3, 4, 5, 6],8.2]]

max_list = list[:] # it is better to use a copy of the original list
for i, k in itertools.combinations(max_list, 2):
    if i[1] == k[1]:
        if i[2] >= k[2] and k in max_list:
            max_list.remove(k)
        elif i[2] < k[2] and i in max_list:
            max_list.remove(i)

print(max_list) # [['p_2', [3, 4, 5, 6], 8.4], ['p_3', [3, 7, 8, 9], 9.1]]
```

> **Update:** to count the max values like 'p_2' = 1 'p_3' = 1

```
counting = {}
for item in max_list:
    counting[item[0]] = max_list.count(item)

print(counting) # {'p_2': 1, 'p_3': 1}
```

> **Update:** new version of the counting.

```
list = list = [['point_21', [5, 18, 19, 21], 21.25], 
    ['point_21', [5, 18, 19, 22], 22.05], 
    ['point_21', [5, 18, 20, 21], 21.25], 
    ['point_21', [5, 18, 20, 22], 22.01], 
    ['point_21', [5, 18, 21, 22], 22.058], 
    ['point_21', [5, 19, 20, 21], 21.5625], 
    ['point_21', [5, 18, 19, 21], 21.25], 
    ['point_20', [5, 17, 19, 22], 20], 
    ['point_20', [5, 16, 20, 21], 21.252], 
    ['point_20', [5, 19, 20, 22], 22.9], 
    ['point_20', [5, 1, 21, 22], 22.6], 
    ['point_20', [5, 12, 20, 21], 21.56]]
```

Assume, you have the `list` above. It contains 12 items. After running the alogithms that compute the `max_list` (i.e. the first code), you will have the list `max_list`that contains 11 items, because one item have been removed (duplication).

```
max_list = [['point_21', [5, 18, 19, 22], 22.05],
        ['point_21', [5, 18, 20, 21], 21.25],
        ['point_21', [5, 18, 20, 22], 22.01],
        ['point_21', [5, 18, 21, 22], 22.058],
        ['point_21', [5, 19, 20, 21], 21.5625],
        ['point_21', [5, 18, 19, 21], 21.25],
        ['point_20', [5, 17, 19, 22], 20],
        ['point_20', [5, 16, 20, 21], 21.252],
        ['point_20', [5, 19, 20, 22], 22.9],
        ['point_20', [5, 1, 21, 22], 22.6],
        ['point_20', [5, 12, 20, 21], 21.56]]
```

For that, here is the counting algorithm:

```
counting = {}
points = set([item[0] for item in max_list if item[0]])

for point in points:
    counting[point] = len([1 for item in max_list if item[0]==point])

print(counting) # {'point_21': 6, 'point_20': 5}
```

Comment: Thanks codrelphi. I do not know why but it does not show me whole points in the max_list. In my main list of lists which is pretty huge, one point is repeated 4046, but when I run your code it does not show it at all. For all other points the count is 1 which is not correct

Comment: the counting part is an extension of the previous code (`max_list`). It is difficult to understand the problem you get now since I don't have your original data.

Comment: Maybe, you should update your code with more details or create another post/thread.

Comment: I I figured it out how can I solve the first problem and the only problem I have right now is that the count for all points = 1.

Comment: Yes, it is correct. `max_list = [['p_2', [3, 4, 5, 6], 8.4], ['p_3', [3, 7, 8, 9], 9.1]]`, so the result is `{'p_2': 1, 'p_3': 1}`

Comment: To help you, give me for example 10 or 20 items of your `max_list`

Comment: A = [['point_21', [5, 18, 19, 21], [16, 16], 21.25],
 ['point_21', [5, 18, 19, 22], 22.05],
 ['point_21', [5, 18, 20, 21], 21.25],
 ['point_21', [5, 18, 20, 22], 22.01],
 ['point_21', [5, 18, 21, 22], 22.058],
 ['point_21', [5, 19, 20, 21], 21.5625],
    ['point_21', [5, 18, 19, 21], 21.25],
 ['point_20', [5, 17, 19, 22],20],
 ['point_20', [5, 16, 20, 21],21.252],
 ['point_20', [5, 19, 20, 22],22.9],
 ['point_20', [5, 1, 21, 22],22.6],
 ['point_20', [5, 12, 20, 21],21.56]]

Comment: But when I run your code it shows {'point_21': 1, 'point_20': 1}

Comment: Check `A`, the first list contains `[16, 16]`, is it not a mistake ?

Comment: I update the code. Take a look on the lastest update. It resolves your problem. Now, the code should work perfectly.

Comment: I don't know how to say thank you enough codrelphi.

Answer (score 1):

You can sort by the second element and then use `itertools.groupby()` to group the elements with the same second element. This will give you groups where all of the second element are the same. After that `max()` can be used based on the third element:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

second = itemgetter(1)
third  = itemgetter(2)

max_list = [max(g, key=third) for k, g in groupby(sorted(l, key=second), key=second)]
# [['p_2', [3, 4, 5, 6], 8.4], ['p_3', [3, 7, 8, 9], 9.1]]
```

Comment: Thank you so much Mark. Just a quick question since count() does not work on list of the lists, how can I find out the number of times that each point (i.e 'p_1', 'p_2' , .. ) had the max value? What I mean is that sth that shows me :
'p_2' = 1
'p_3' = 1
...

Comment: I update my code. You can check how to achieve this goal in my code.